# Show that any finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-groups, permutations, group-homomorphism

We are told the following:

Let $S_n$ denote the permutation group on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and let $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices.  Now assume the following fact:

*for each $n$ there is a group homomorphism $\varphi : S_n \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\ker (\varphi) = \{\iota\}$, where $\iota$ is the identity permutation.*

**How do I show that any finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$?**

I realise I need to use Cayley's theorem for a finite group which is:

*Every finite group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.*

However, I am unsure how I can answer this question.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know about composition of homomorphisms?

Comment: So, by Cayley's theorem, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, and you know $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(\Bbb C)$. You're unable to put those two facts together?

Comment: @JohnHughes  I know that if $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and $\theta : H \rightarrow K$ is a homomorphism then the composition of both is a homomorphism too.  Is that what you mean? Also, is $S_n$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Trying to spell it out. You have an injective homomorphism $f:G\to S_n$ by Cayley. You have an injective homomorphism $\phi:S_n\to GL_n(\Bbb{R})$. What can you say about $\phi\circ f$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok I think I understand! Therefore the composition is injective.  Is it is also Surjective?  Because if it is I gather than then it will be bijective and therefore isomorphic.

Comment: It doesn't need to be surjective, *any* map is surjective onto its image.

Answer (score 6):

You've almost made it to the end !

Let $G$ be a finite groupe and $n = \text{Card}(G)$.

Caley's theorem states that there exists $\phi \in \text{Hom}(G, S_n)$ which is injective, which means that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

We will make $S_n$ "act" on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. We will define for every $\sigma \in S_n$ the matrix :
$$M_{\sigma} = (\delta_{\sigma(i), j})$$

where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta defined by : $\delta_{a, b} = \begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } a = b \\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

These $M_{\sigma}$ are elements of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ because $\forall \sigma \in S_n, \ M_{\sigma} \times M_{\sigma^{-1}} = M_{\sigma^{-1}} \times M_{\sigma} = I_n$.

Let $\phi' : \sigma \mapsto M_{\sigma}$. $\phi' \in \text{Hom}(S_n, \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))$ and is injective, so $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

then, let $\theta = \phi' \circ \phi$. $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are injective morphisms, so $\theta$ is an injective morphism from $G$ to $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$. That means $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, which is, in our case, $\text{Im}(\theta)$.

Comment: I assume you are correct, but I have only understood a bit of your answer as out notes do not extend that far.

Comment: What do you want me to explain more ?

Comment: Well, we were meant to use the following information:  If $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms, then $g \circ f$ is an isomorphism, If $\ker (\varphi) = \{e\}$ then $\varphi$ is injective, an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism and $\ker (\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism.  Also Cayley's theorem for finite groups.  With that information we are meant to answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand what blocks you : I've only used injective morphisms, where you ask for a bijective morphism, is that right ?

In that case, I'm going to change a bit of notations from my post above.

Let $\varphi$ be an injective morphism from $G$ to $H$, where $G$ and $H$ are any groups. Then, we can define :
$$\varphi_{\text{bij}} : \begin{matrix}
G & \longrightarrow & \text{Im}(\varphi) \\
g & \longmapsto & \varphi(g)
\end{matrix}$$

$\varphi_{\text{bij}}$ is an injective and surjective morphism, so $\varphi_{\text{bij}}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Let's apply this : by cayley, we have $\phi : G \to S_n$ which is injective, so by our process, we have $\phi_{\text{bij}}$ from $G$ to $\text{Im}(\phi)$ which is an isomorphism.

In the same way as above, we define :
$$\phi' : \begin{matrix}
\text{Im}(\phi) & \longrightarrow & \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})
\sigma & \longmapsto & M_{\sigma}
\end{matrix}$$

Let's study $\phi'$'s injectivity :
$$\sigma \in \text{Ker}(\phi') \iff M_\sigma = I_n \iff \forall i \in [\![1, n]\!], \sigma(i) = i \iff \sigma = \iota$$

From that, we conclude that $\text{Ker}(\phi') = \{\iota\}$.

Comment: We now know that $\phi'$ is injective, and by our process, we have an isomorphism ${\phi'}_{\text{bij}}$ from $\text{Im}(\phi)$ to $\text{Im}(\phi')$, which is a subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Last thing : let $\theta = {\phi'}_{\text{bij}} \circ \phi_{\text{bij}}$. ${\phi'}_{\text{bij}}$ and $\phi_{\text{bij}}$ are isomorphisms, so $\theta$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Im}(\phi')$, which is a subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I hope it's clear that time !

Comment: We will define for every $\sigma \in S_n$ the matrix:
$$M_{\sigma} = (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}).$$ Is it correct? I have put i in last j.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is similar to @Wirius's, but includes an example.

---

We seek a homomorphism $\phi : S_n \rightarrow \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$.

- Let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Notation) that sends $[1, n] \rightarrow [1, n]$.
- Let $M \in \text{GL}_n (\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix that sends a vector $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then one simple identification is:

$$M_{ij} = (\phi(\sigma))_{ij} = \delta_{i \, \sigma(j)}$$

---

To see why this is a good choice, let $n = 3$ and $\sigma = (1 \; 3 \; 2)$. Then:

$$\phi(\sigma) = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix acts on a vector $\vec{x} = (x_1 \; x_2 \; x_3)^T$ to give:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Just as we expect.

Answer (score 1):

By Cayley's theorem for finite groups:

*Every finite group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.*

Let $f: G \rightarrow S_n$ be a homomorphism and also an isomorphism.

We also know that $\varphi : S_n \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a homomorphism.

Since $\ker (\varphi) = \{\iota\}$ where $\iota$ is the identity permutation, then $\varphi$ is injective.  Furthermore since $\text{im} (\varphi) = GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $\varphi$ is also surjective.  This means that $\varphi$ is a bijective homomorphism, which means it is an isomorphism.

Therefore since $f$ and $\varphi$ are both isomorphisms, then $\varphi \circ f$ is an isomorphism too.  Hence any finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$.

This would be my attempt at the answer.

Comment: Of course that $\operatorname{im}(\varphi)\neq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$; $S_n$ is finite; whereas $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ isn't. But you proved correctly that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ contains a subgroup isomorphic with $S_n$.